# How does the cartesian product of Borel Sets work?

Tags: stochastic-processes, borel-sets

I have that $$(\vec{a},\vec{b}] = (a_{1}, b_{1}] \times (a_{2}, b_{2}] \times (a_{3}, b_{3}] \times ... \times (a_{k}, b_{k}]$$ as a definition for Borel Sets. Now I know that for example in $R^2$.
$$(a_{1}, b_{1}] \times (a_{2}, b_{2}] = \{(a_{1}, a_{2}], (a_{1}, b_{2}], (b_{1}, a_{2}], (b_{1}, b_{2}]\}$$ But how can a vector interval equal a set ? $$(\begin{bmatrix} a_{1} \\ a_{2}\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} b_{1} \\ b_{2}\end{bmatrix}] = \{(a_{1}, a_{2}], (a_{1}, b_{2}], (b_{1}, a_{2}], (b_{1}, b_{2}]\}$$

Comment: The symbol $\times$ here I think is called a Cartesian product, not a cross product

Comment: $(a_1, b_1] \times (a_2, b_2]$ is a rectangle in $R^2$ consisting of pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $a_1 < x_1 \le b_1$ and $a_2 < x_2 \le b_2$. It isn't a set of four intervals as you've written.

Comment: I'm confused by your notation when you write $(a_1,b_1] \times (a_2,b_2] = \{(a_1,a_2],(a_1,b_2],(b_1,a_2],(b_1,b_2]\}$.  On the right you have a set of intervals, i.e. a set of sets.  Is that what you wanted, rather than a set of numbers in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @angryavian Ok I see, so its the set of all the points that are in that rectangle?